# List in powershell processes that do not have services and their PID's

Tags: powershell

Can you please help me to list in PowerShell processes that do not have service along with their PIDs?

I cannot list all those processes with `N/A` Services, I have tried some commands, without success:

```
Get-process | where-services {$_.Status -eq "N/A"}
Get-process | sort-object {$_.Status -eq "N/A"}
tasklist /svc /FI "SERVICES ne N/A"
tasklist /v /FI "SERVICES ne N/A"
```

Thank you,

Comment: can you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: You've not shown any of your own code or any that indication you've tried researching/searching for a solution. I'd recommend reading [ask] as at the moment your question is missing the basics that are expected when asking a question. Your question is likely to be downvoted and closed until you show the basics.

Comment: Aside from the lack of code your question is quite unclear to me. What do you mean by "do not have services"?

Comment: I cannot list all those processes with N/A Services. I have tried some commands, without success:                     
Get-process | where-services {$_.Status -eq "N/A"} //
Get-process | sort-object {$_.Status -eq "N/A"}   //                            
tasklist /svc /FI "SERVICES ne N/A"  // 
tasklist /v /FI "SERVICES ne N/A"

Comment: And we have code! Always include it when you ask a question -- even if it doesn't work, it still helps us with understanding what you're trying to do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `Get-Service` doesn't return the Process Id info for the processes that the services run. However you can get that information via the WMI `Win32_Service` class which has a `ProcessId` property:

```
$ServicePids = (Get-Wmiobject win32_service).ProcessId | Sort-Object -Unique
$ProcessPids = (Get-Process).Id | Sort-Object -Unique

$Pids = Compare-Object $ServicePids $ProcessPids -PassThru

Get-Process -Id $Pids | Select Name,Id
```

You can get the Id of the processes with `Get-Process` and then use `Compare-Object` to compare them. The `-Passthru` switch returns just the Pid values (rather than a comparison object).

I also use `Sort-Object -Unique` to reduce both lists to sorted unique lists so that they compare correctly.

Finally if you want the output to be similar to `tasklist /svc` you can use `Get-Process` again to return objects for the resultant Ids, which we returned to `$Pids`. I've used the `Select` cmdlet to filter that down to just the Name and Id fields, but you could obviously modify this to whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate this very much. I have tried it but it does not seem to work. The idea of the question is for the output to be similar with the one you receive from tasklist /svc, but it should list only those processes that have N/A under the Services Tab (the processes that have No service - N/A).

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think you can get the sort of output you're looking for by just using `Get-Process` again with the resultant list of Pids. It's possible to do all this with less steps, but i've laid it out to maximise readability/understanding.

Comment: Thanks again, I appreciate the help. Sorry, but it still does not work. Could you please advise what would the other option be (the one with less steps)? I have been tried for the last few days to resolve this, with no success.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Perhaps I can help you to debug what's going wrong.

Comment: I receive an error after $Pids = Compare-Object $ServicePids $ProcessPids -PassThru // It mentions that the parameter is null.

Comment: If you want a non-PowerShell solution that filters the output of tasklist, you could just do this `tasklist /svc | findstr 'N/A'`. PowerShell is better because you have usable/object output at the end.

Comment: Your error suggests that either `$ServicePids` or `$ProcessPids` are empty. Check if those variables have any content, and if one doesn't, look in to why the code that gets the Pid values isn't working. Perhaps (for example) try running `Get-Wmiobject win32_service` on its own to check on your system you actually get a `ProcessId` property come back.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!                                                                                  tasklist /svc | findstr 'N/A' worked.